# How to use an image overlay (position:relative) above buttons and links (form) without interfering the clickable events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The title of the question is pretty explanatory. I want my buttons and links in a form to ignore the image above them. I want to "overlay" the whole page (even the text fields and areas) with the image. I would appreciate a **CSS code**, but if you think that it's not possible with CSS, I would appreciate another solution as well (e.g. vanilla js to put in a script tag).

What have I tried? I tried to play with the z-index, but I lose the "overlay" effect if my form is above the image. I tried to make everything in my form "transparent", but it's not the effect that I want and it's a lot of work. I thought about turning off the clickable event/s of the image? Does that make any sense? I have no idea if such thing is even possible, but it seems like a probable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while asking the question and explaining my thoughts. :D

```
pointer-events: none
```